# My destructor does not appear to hit every node in the tree as I have memory leaks, what am I missing here?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, valgrind, delete-operator

EDIT: So I'm an idiot and forgot to SSH my updated .cpp when working with valgrind. Anyways I've updated the code below to represent new changes. Unfortunately I'm still getting some leaking with the stuff below and I'll I'm doing is creating a tree which means somewhere some information is still not being deleted properly.

Here is my destructor for my tree which calls the recursive helper.

```
//---------------------------- destructor --------------------------------
BinTree::~BinTree() {
    makeEmptyHelper(root);
}

//---------------------------- makeEmptyHelper --------------------------------
void BinTree::makeEmptyHelper(Node*& current) {

    if (current != NULL) {
        makeEmptyHelper(current->left);
        makeEmptyHelper(current->right);
        delete current->data;
        delete current;
        current = NULL;
        //delete current;
    }
}
```

Here is my node struct:

```
struct Node {
    NodeData* data; // pointer to data object 
    Node* left; // left subtree pointer 
    Node* right; // right subtree pointer 
};
```

NodeData is a separate object class that has its own destructor which works properly.

Comment: Are you deleting data somewhere? I mean you commented out delete current->data;. Perhaps the destructor for Node does that. Edit: But Node does not have a destructor.

Comment: Realized I'm an idiot because I wasn't using the updated .cpp just my main so I thought that commenting and uncommenting that line had no effect because I was running the same code every time -.-

I've uncommented that and it's definitely fixed some of the leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete `current` before you set it to `NULL`, not afterwards.  In fact, there is no reason to set `current` to `NULL` in the first place: the pointer `current` is passed by value, so updating it has no external effect.

Note that it is legal to `delete NULL`, but it is a no-op.

Comment: Could probably just get rid of the `current = NULL;` anyway. It's just nulling a local copy of the pointer.

Comment: True, I will add that.

Comment: Yes sorry I was playing around with it earlier to see if it had any difference whether passed by reference or passed by value. I DO want to pass it by reference because later on my code relies upon hitting NULL while traversing down the tree so in this case I do want current = NULL and I did change it back to pass by reference.

Comment: Um, repeated editing of the question makes it hard to keep the answer relevant.  Rather than pursue a moving target, I will leave the answer as is.

Comment: I agree. It would be hard for anyone to understand my comment or your answer since the question is no longer what it originally was. And now the question has the answer in it so it may seem pointless.